# Qt space around QPushButton in QHBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QLabel and a QPushButton added to a QHBoxLayout. The QLabel has its margins set to 0 and the layout has margin and content margins set to 0. The label and button have the same background color and the button has border set to none. However, the button still looks with a brighter color than the label and there is some extra space around the button, so it doesn't look like it's "glued" to the label. I want them to look like one big widget.

Comment: If this problem is reproducible on Windows with Aero theme, please try to switch to Classic theme and let us know what do you see.

Comment: I am on Debian Jessie

Comment: @Ilya there seems to be slight space between the label and the button, but I don't know why, I've set anything related to margin on both widgets and the layout to 0

Comment: Ok, thank you for this additional info. Could you add screenshot and your code which creates all these widgets? What is your Qt version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt, margins describe the space surrounding the layout. In newer versions of Qt, the margins on the top/bottom/left/right can be set individually through `setContentsMargins()`.

The space *between* widgets in the *same* layout is described by the [spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) property. The spacing has nothing to do with the margins. Try calling `hboxLayout->setSpacing(0);` This should work.

Comment: All set and still, there is margin. styleSheet-margin destroys the layout

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I have coded a widget with similar behavior. To avoid problems with margins and colors I can recommend to use second QPushButton button instead of QLabel and set both buttons to be flat with `btn->setFlat(true);`